# React node to be removed is not a child of this node html5 drag and drop

Tags: html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

Background:

I have a react app which has a dropdpown with some teams and on selecting a team it will load the possible client and selected clients(if any selected earlier)

The issue is when i drag a value from possible to selected, the value gets appended in the selected but with the below error
[possible to selected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzP4S.png)

and when i move some existing clients in selected to possible i will get the below error and the value gets shown twice.
[twice added error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhumA.png)

This is the code for drop.

```
drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
let p = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.plist.refs.dnd);
    let pItems = (p.getElementsByTagName('li'));
    let s = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.slist.refs.dnd);
    let sItems = s.getElementsByTagName('li');
  this.setState({
      possibleClients: createClientJson( pItems),
      selectedClients: createClientJson(sItems),
});
}

function createClientJson(items) {
  let result = [];
  for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    result.push(JSON.parse(items[i].getAttribute('data-info')));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: i am not able to add more than 2 images. the visual looks like this:.............        possible list  dnd                        selected list dnd

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, can you please try and be a bit more specific about your problem? Why are you using manual dom manipulation when you can have react do it for you?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Basically, when the user selects a team an api call will be made and it gets me possible and selected list so i set the possible state and selected state.. Now the user can drag from possible to selected or selected to possible. so the state should also be updated with the latest values..because i will save it back to db... so are you  telling me that if i drag and drop, then the state will have the latest values already?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen say if i have 2 clients in selected and one in possible. If i move the one in possible to selected and when i click save and if i refer as this.state.selectedClients then it will only give me back 2 not three.. so i was getting from the list and setting it. Please tell me where am i doing wrong here